# C# DataGridViewへの行の追加について

Tags: c#, datagridview

お世話になります。

DataGridViewからDataGridViewRowを生成し、そこに名前を指定して値を
セットしてからDataGridViewに追加するという、基本的なことをやりたいのですが、
どうもうまくいきません。

コードを記述しますので、間違いを指摘していただければ幸いです。

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

    string[] stDefines = {
            "No_204","営_60","氏名_210","担当者名_120","開始_145","終了_145"
    };

    int idx = 0;
    foreach (string s in stDefines)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_"));
　　　　//  ↓ ここで名前を指定しています。
        col.Name = "col" + s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_"));
        col.ReadOnly = true;
        col.Width = int.Parse(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("_") + 1));
        col.DisplayIndex = idx;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        idx++;
    }

    this.Refresh();

    DataGridViewRow dgvr = new DataGridViewRow();

    dgvr.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

　　// ↓ここでcolNoというcolumnNameはないといわれます
    dgvr.Cells["colNo"].Value = "0101010101010101";

   this.dataGridView1.Add(dgvr);
}
```

前半部分にて、各カラムに『col + 「名前」』として定義しているのですが、なぜか
値を入れるときに名前がないというのですが、その理由がわかりません。

Rowの生成はうまくいっており、きちんと項目数も六個とみているのですが、実際に値を
入れるときに失敗しています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問の編集時、コード部分のみを選択した状態で`{}`をクリックすると見やすく整形されるので次回から試してください。

Comment: すみません。修正もありがとうございます。以後留意します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因は下記通りです。
CreateCellsメソッドは、行のDataGridViewCellCollectionをクリアし、 dataGridViewパラメーター CellTemplateの各列の**プロパティで再初期化**します。

一般的の書き方でRowを追加

```
int index=this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["colNo"].Value = "0101010101010101";
```

特別な処理があるとき（セルにほかのコンポーネント利用する時）

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewTextBoxCell textboxcell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
textboxcell.Value = "aaa";
row.Cells.Add(textboxcell);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。ご指摘の方法で思い通りに動きました。CreateCellsを使用していたこと自体に問題があったみたいですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

他者さまの検証結果をそのままURLを張りますが、仕様のようです。
https://jehupc.exblog.jp/12573968/

元々、.NET WinForm向けコントロールのComboBoxやListBoxやDataGridViewなどは、
DataSourceプロパティにList＜T＞、DataTable、BindingSourceいずれかを設定して使用する想定です。

特に、DataGridViewの場合はDataTableかBindingSourceをバインドする運用が推奨前提になっています。
（ListジェネリックをDataSourceに設定してしまうと、読み取り専用になります。）

```js
    // .designer.cs

    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

    // .cs

    private DataTable srcRef;

    private void たとえばLoadCustomersとか()
    {
        // deginer側でバインド設定済みなら不要
        // dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // 中略... DBやXmlやJsonからロードしてDataTableに詰め込むなど
        this.srcRef = table
        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

    }
```

このように、UIパーツ（DataGridView）と実データ（DataTable）にし、
・ロジックからの操作は常にDataTableに直接変更を書ける
・UI側からのイベントの場合も、そのArgのRowIndexやColIndexをもとに実データを取り出して変更をかける

などします

Comment: ありがとうございます。まだ試してはいませんが、これだけの手をかけなければならないとなると、使うこと自体躊躇しますね。ほかサイト様のサンプルなどを見て組んだつもりなのですが、最近の.Netになって、今までできてたことができなくなってしまったということなのでしょうか…。

Comment: 出来なくなった、ということはないと思います。昔からDataGridViewはバグまがいな仕様が大量にある感じですね。また、DataTableは今は昔の2005年ごろのADO.NET、SQL ServerのVisual Studioデザイナ連携前提の機能なので、デザイナ操作+10行ぐらいの記述でDBテーブルの内容をDataTableに取得でき、それをDataGridViewに渡すだけでテーブルの内容を勝手に一覧表示できるのがウリでした。（今でいうRailsフォロワーのscaffoldingの前身…とも言えるかも）

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = dataGridView1.Add();
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
row.Cells["colNo"].Value = "0101010101010101";
```

でどうですか？

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ご指摘のコードですと、dataGridView1.Add()でAddというメソッドがないということだったので、Rows.Addにしたのですが、それでもやはり同じくcolNoが見つかりませんと言われますね。

Comment: @たたぱたさん、対応.NET frameworkを4.8に上げて試してみてください。